# Merging unlinked files into source

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a copy of a source controlled folder with a lot of changes that's not currently linked to our Source control.

The contents of both copies this folder have been heavily edited since the copy was taken and no I've to merge them somehow.

How can I merge a copy not linked to source control to a copy that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is simple:

1. Make sure you have an unmodifed repository state in your repository. Commit your modifications, if there are some.
2. In the repository: Update to the **predecessor** of the commit with which you want to merge your unversioned files.
3. Now copy all files of the unversioned directory into the working directory of your repository. Add the needed untracked files and commit the changes. This will result in a new head in the repository and you'll have at least two: your previously tracked one and the previously untracked ones
4. Now merge the two heads and solve any conflict in a manner which suits you.

It's always a good idea to keep a copy of things (both, original repository and unversioned directory) should things go differently than you bid for... it's easier to start anew than undo a commit or even an unwanted merge.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Copy the **unversioned** files inside the **versioned** folder, then commit. Not very wise, because the content merged will be out of your control. When you see what is wrong, it will be too late to fix.
2. - **Initialize** a mercurial repository in the **unversioned** folder, add the files, **commit**.
   - Add your main repository path in the `Synchronize` section,  can be your local repository.
   - Click the `Options` button, enable the `Force push or pull` checkbox. **Pull** revisions from your **main repository**.
   - **Update** to the revision you want to merge.
   - **Merge**  with the new revision.
   - Finally, **push** to the main repository.

**WARNING**: Always make a backup of your files, if you are not sure about this procedure.

This isn't dangerous, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Method #1 will not merge anything. It will simply create a new head commit with the state of the files which were previously uncommitted. You cannot merge a commit with its predecessor, thus a merge will fail

Comment: Would work if all the files of the unversioned folder were new.  The idea was to avoid doing the merge. Your answer was a mix of my two methods. One was too simple to work, maybe the other was too complex. You hit the middle and won, I rest defeated.